# How to change a user's nickname, knowing their id, but not knowing their member object (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Please help. For some reason I can't get a member object from id

````
@bot.command()
async def shift_nick(ctx: commands.Context, new_nick : str , line: str = None) #line - Secret string that I use to search for the user id in the database

..... #Working with the database. As a result I get the value of the user_id variable and the value is correct

user =  ctx.guild.get_member(int(user_id)) #And for some reason the value is None
await user.edit(nick=new_nick)#And because l is None, I can't change the username on the server```
````

Comment: You never define user_id?

Comment: My bot has a registration in which it saves discord_id. If a user needs to change their nickname, they ask for it from a certain group of people who have the right to use this command. The user simply gives their secret string, which was given to them by the bot during registration, and they change their nickname. You may be wondering: "Why do this if you can give the user the ability to change the nickname", but under the conditions of the existence of this bot, it is " dangerous"

Comment: Are you sure that `user_id` is correct? According to the docs, [ctx.guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) will return `None` if no member is found.

Comment: user_is is correct and that's for sure. Maybe my bot doesn't see all users, but it can't be

Comment: Also check if user_id is a string. int() returns None if user_id is an Integer.
Could be also nice if you debug a little bit like checking if user really got found.

Comment: And also, discord is currently again forcing with Intents. I have a related problem where I can't get guilds or channels from servers. Try to upgrade your discord.py, could help

Comment: As mentioned by @Ari24, you need to have the `members` intent. See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the value returned from `get_member` is `None` is very likely to be that you haven't enabled the Members privileged gateway intent.

To fix your problem, I'd try the following. First, enable the Members privileged intent on your Discord application by going to `https://discord.com/developers/applications/<app_id>/bot` and checking "Server Members Intent".

Then, use the Members intents in the following way:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# The remainder of your code...
```